# Why temporarily add 1 to an error when squaring it?

Tags: optimization, error

I'm trying to understand how the optimisation is working in an algorithm.  In support of the optimisation, errors are calculated.

For one type of error, before it returns the value, it squares the number, then subtracts one:

```
x = 1 + error / maxOverallError
error = x * x - 1
```

Does adding the 1, squaring, then subtracting the one have any statistical significance?

Does it overcome any issues?

Comment: The error is nonpositive for any estimate that's within 1 unit of the actual value. Perhaps this error function is allowing for slight deviations from actual to be non-penalized? I'd expect negative errors to be rounded to 0, though, as I'm not sure how to interpret negative error.

Comment: ok. I'd asked the editors to unlock the question so I could provide a formal answer.  I'll put one in here as a comment, instead.  The above construct is to overcome the issue where squaring a fraction gives a smaller fraction.  We're squaring the result error to exaggerate them.  But, squaring a number less than one actually makes it smaller.  So, the algorithm adds `one` to the result (to force it to be above one), then squares it, then removes the original `one`.
Well, that's my current best guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the original error values `e = actual - estimated` with a cost function `C(e) = (squaring) * (negative)` that better suits your need for the optimization algorithm.

**Squaring** the error creates a high penalty on larger errors, which can accelerate optimization algorithms such as the [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

**Multiplying by -1** forces the cost function to be negative, which usually occurs when you are using a maximization optimization algorithm, i.e. optimizing by maximizing the cost function.

[image: Error vs Cost Function]

Edit: Added source of plot in Python.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
plt.plot(x, x**x, label="square")
plt.plot(x, x, label="linear")
plt.plot(x, x**x*-1, label="squared_negative")

plt.ylabel("Cost Function")
plt.xlabel("Error")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your submission @francisco-fonseca .  Late that night I realised I'd misinterpreted the operator significance (BIDMAS).  So, the square is performed first, and then the `1` is subtracted.  I've had a go at explaining this in a comment on my original question.